# How to change the start of the chart to -2? is that possible? i use apexcharts js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, charts, apexcharts

I have data with `min = -2` and `max = 6`. I want to make a chart with that data, but on the apexcharts chart it starts from `0`, not from `-2`, even though I changed the min **yaxis** to `-2`

[this is output with my options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFhQm.png)

this is my options and data

```
const chartData = [
                { x: 'A', y: -2 },
                { x: 'B', y: 3 },
                { x: 'C', y: 6 },
            ];

            var options = {
                series: [{
                    name: 'Persentase',
                    data: chartData
                }],
                chart: {
                    offsetX: 20,
                    animations: {
                        enabled: false,
                    },
                    type: 'bar',
                    height: 600,
                    toolbar: {
                        show: false,
                    },
                    width: '90%'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        borderRadiusApplication: 'end',
                        borderRadiusWhenStacked: 'last',
                        horizontal: true,
                        distributed: true,
                        dataLabels: {
                            position: 'top'
                        },
                    },
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        colors: ['#333']
                    },
                    formatter: function (val, opts) {
                        return val;
                    },
                    textAnchor: 'start',
                    offsetX: -10,
                    offsetY: 0,
                },
                colors: ['#ff7c80', '#cc99ff', '#ffff1a', '#99ccff', '#c6e0b4', '#ffd34d'],
                yaxis:{
                    min: -2,
                    max: 6,
                    labels: {
                        show: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            fontSize: '13px',
                        },
                    },
                },
                xaxis: {
                    show: true,
                },
                legend: {
                    show: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
            };
```

[what I want is like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWgpu.png), the chart starts from `-2` not `0`, how to change it in apexcharts? is that possible or not?

Comment: The bars in a `bar`  chart start from zero, regardless of the limits  you set for the y axis. If you want bars that start at other values you can use `type: 'rangeBar'` and set the start and end values explicitly, e.g., [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aej6uo3L/). The change of `chartData` can be done programmatically but it's not fully clear how you want to make this change; for instance how would you treat a second negative value, like `-1` - would the bar start at zero, or at -2?

Answer (score 0):

the min: -2 you must put it on the X axis

```
xaxis: {
  show: true,
  min: -2
},
```

**Basic Example**

https://jsfiddle.net/SeiryuV/qk0c4pb8/14/